# Use np.where with a range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to use two conditions where one is a range of numbers like the following:

```
df['COL1'] = np.where(df['COL1'] == 4 & (df['COL2'] in range(28,40)), 20, df['COL1'])
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Just wondering if there is a way to get this working or something that could be easier than using `np.where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and also note the parantheses:

```
np.where((df["COL1"] == 4) & (df["COL2"].between(28, 39)), 20, df["COL1"])
```

`range` excludes end-point and `between` includes by default, hence 39.